# var_dump for variable in django templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

How can I see what data and fields the variable contains in the template? Suppose I have a list of courses and I do filtering by active. How can I see what fields the courses have (start date, name, slug, etc ...) I have the variable "events" but I don’t understand how to see fields of this variable and what they contain.

```
events.name
events.slug
```

sry for my eng

Comment: events is Model or QuerySet ?

Comment: QuerySet from views in template.html

Comment: This is also possible, but make "dump" inside views, not in templates. You do not like this idea ?

Comment: ok ill try but wher i can see results?

Answer (score -1):

You can see results inside terminal. When you are working on code on Development server and run `python manage.py runserver` Django has "Real-Time" log.

Imagine that you have Person model in **Django**,,,

## models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'person'
```

## views.py

```
def index(request):
    person = Person.objects.get(pk=1) # For example try to retrieve row from database
    print(person.__dict__) # This will return dict with your model fields and associated values => {'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7fcf5e8d6e48>, 'name': 'myname', 'id': 1, 'surname': 'mysurname'} 
    return JsonResponse({'status_message': 'OK'})
```

Not required to do this inside views.py,,, Maybe you are using `python manage.py shell`. When you have model instance, just print `print(instance.__dict__)`